# matrix equation for polish student

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B, C, D$ will be square matrices $n  \times  n$ over $R$.
 
Suppose that with $AB ^{T}$ and $CD ^{T}$ are symmetrical and $AD ^{T} - BC ^{T} = I$. 
Show that:
$A ^{T} D - C ^{T} B = I$:

I'm trying to transform the last equation, but it comes to me something like this: 
$A^{T} C   = C ^{T} A$
I do not know I can prove it. maybe I do it not as it should be, I would ask for any hint.

Comment: what does `polish student` have to do with anything? I may be dense in asking such a question.

Comment: Keep the english simple if replying, I should think.

Comment: @Paul ah thank you, we are doing that now? maybe a tag will be required at some point knowing how things go on MSE!

Comment: Putnam 1986-B6.

Comment: Here's a hint taken from the relevant MAA book http://imgur.com/poEbE21

Answer (score 0):

Catalin Zara has effectively answered this. Solution [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~giventh/19109_86s.pdf), B6.